# No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

Tags: bootstrap-4, vuejs3, vite, bootstrap-vue

I try to start a brand new Vue project and want to add Bootstrap to it.

All is good, but when i try to launch it, i have this error :

`node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7: ERROR: No matching export in node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"`

i started with `npm init vue@latest`
after that i done an `npm install`.
To install bootstrap i made `npm install bootstrap bootstrap-vue`.
If at this point i made an npm run all is good but when i try to import bootstrap in my project i get the error. Here is how i use it :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { BootstrapVue } from 'bootstrap-vue'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import './assets/main.css'

const app = createApp(App)

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

and here is the trace of the error :

```
 npm run dev

> test@0.0.0 dev C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test
> vite


  VITE v4.0.4  ready in 2204 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7:
      13 │ import Vue from 'vue';
         ╵        ~~~

X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7:
      13 │ import Vue from 'vue';
         ╵        ~~~

X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7:
      13 │ import Vue from 'vue';
         ╵        ~~~

X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7:
      13 │ import Vue from 'vue';
         ╵        ~~~

X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7:
      13 │ import Vue from 'vue';
         ╵        ~~~

X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7:
      13 │ import Vue from 'vue';
         ╵        ~~~

X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/portal-vue/dist/portal-vue.esm.js:13:7:
      13 │ import Vue from 'vue';
         ╵        ~~~

(node:28520) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Build failed with 7 errors:
node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"
node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"
node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"
node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"
node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:13:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm-bundler.js" for import "default"
...
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1604:15)
    at C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1056:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1476:61)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1054:7)
    at C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1166:14
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:701:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:756:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\ycolin\projet\test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:677:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:28520) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:28520) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BootstrapVue is compatible with Vue 2.6.

> "With more than 85 components, over 45 available plugins, several directives, and 1000+ icons, BootstrapVue provides one of the most comprehensive implementations of the Bootstrap v4.5 component and grid system available for Vue.js v2.6, complete with extensive and automated WAI-ARIA accessibility markup." [source](https://bootstrap-vue.org/)

You are using Vue 3. Moreover, it is still stuck in Bootstrap 4 and might be incompatible with Vite (which is most likely the case, since it loves to be incompatible with a lot of libraries). Use the bootstrap npm package instead.

( `npm i bootstrap` )

Comment: So if i understand well, i must use bootstrap instead of bootstrapVue ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no wrapper for bootstrap for Vue 3 yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working pretty fine !

Answer (score 4):

`BootstrapVue` is now compatible with Vue 3 using [@vue-compat](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html#upgrade-workflow).
You can read more about it here: [Vue.js 3.x initial support](https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3).
Use this [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-vue-with-compat) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a workaround to use BootstrapVue with Vue 3. The only thing you need is to install https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/compat package as project dependency.